# Integration of $\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|y|} }dy$ for $y<0$

Tags: integration, analysis

I tried to solve $x'(t)=\sqrt{|x(t)|}$ by using separation of variables.
So I did $$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{x'(s)}{\sqrt{|x(s)|}}ds$$
and used the substituion $y=x(s)$, which gave me the integral
$$\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|y|} }dy$$
If we have $y>0$, I dont't have problems solving this: $2\sqrt{x(t)}-2\sqrt{x(0)}$
But how can I solve the integral if we have $y<0$.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any more information about the initial condition? For instance, $x'$ is always non-negative so if $x(0)>0$, then $x(t)>0$ for all $t>0$, and so $y$ is always positive as well.

It's also perhaps worth noting that this differential equations is one of the typical 'pathological' examples from existence and uniqueness theory for ODE's. Observe that the function $\sqrt{|x|}$ is not Lipschitz on any interval including $x=0$, and if you try to solve this problem with the initial condition $x(0) = 0$ (for instance), you can find infinitely many $C^1$ solutions. (the 'basic' solution is $x = \dfrac{1}{4}t^2 : t \geq 0; x = 0 : t< 0$, and you can get other solutions by translating this to the right any number of units).

Further, if you try and solve this with an initial condition $x(0) < 0$, there's going to be some $t_0 > 0$ so that $x(t_0) = 0$ (this doesn't follow directly from $x' > 0$, but that's at least reasonable intuition), and then you have the uniqueness problem all over again relative to that point.

So, in some sense, it only makes sense to talk about 'solving' this problem with initial data $x(0) > 0$.

Comment: Hi, I do not have any other information

Comment: Ok. Do you understand the rest of my answer though? In particular, do you see why $x(0)>0$ is necessary to have unique solutions?

Comment: Yes, I do - thank you!

Comment: Even specifying $x(0)>0$ does not give a full unique solution. It's unique locally around $t=0$, and for all positive $t$, but moving back in time, the parabola reaches the $t$ axis and then there are two ways to continue moving back in time: one above the $t$-axis and one below.

Comment: Ahh yes, good point. I've assumed (without stating) that we're working on $0 \leq t \leq T$, but I should have made that clear.

Comment: Hold up, I take it back. Just looking at a field plot for the original differential equation, it's clear that solutions are unique no matter where you start until you hit the $t$-axis. Note the differential equation implies $x'$ is never negative, so the downward sides of any parabolas are off limits.

Comment: I think the full family consists of curves that start as a negative upward arcing parabola that eventually reach the $t$-axis. At that point they may stay constant at $0$ for any length of time (or not at all) and then become a positive upward arcing parabola.

Comment: yes - the non-uniqueness isn't due to either the 'up' or 'down' parabola; you're right that you always have to choose one or the other (if you don't choose identically $0$). The problem is that you can 'stay at $0$' for any amount of time.